# Loop through rows to find and update values - Faster

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm made a spreadsheet using google sheets to update inventory. I have a button that will run a script where it compares the values in the "scanner" spreadsheet and loops through the "inventory" spreadsheet to search for the matching barcode and updates its values.
It works but its slow. Could anyone provide any recommendations to make it faster?

Here's what I wrote, I saved the "in scan" items as an array because I read somewhere that its faster compared to .getdisplayvalue() for each line item.

```
function add_Inventory() {
  var invtSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory");
  var inScan = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scanner").getRange("I8:J100").getDisplayValues();
  inScan = inScan.filter(n => n[0]);
  
  
 
  for (let j = 0; j < inScan.length; j++) {
    
    for(let i = 2; i <= invtSS.getLastRow(); i++) {
      if(invtSS.getRange(i,1).getDisplayValue() == inScan[j][1]){
        
        var oldVal = invtSS.getRange(i,6).getValue();
        var newVal = Number(inScan[j][0]);

        invtSS.getRange(i,6).setValue(oldVal + newVal);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'll also provide a link to the google sheet itself [lINK](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12IPkb3wGs8JxTMYui5P-7NuNUcE4qovCqdMRHqCQp1U/edit?usp=sharing)
Please note this is a small fraction of the actual inventory (1000 parts) so it really does go slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

When `getDisplayValue()`, `getValue()`, and `setValue` are used in a loop, the process cost becomes high. [Ref](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/10/12/benchmark-reading-and-writing-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/) I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function add_Inventory2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var invtSS = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
  var inScan = ss.getSheetByName("Scanner").getRange("I8:J100").getValues();
  var obj = inScan.reduce((m, [i, j]) => {
    if (j.toString()) m.set(j, i); // or if (j.toString()) m.set(j, m.has(j) ? m.get(j) + i : i);
    return m;
  }, new Map());
  var range = invtSS.getRange("A2:E" + invtSS.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues().map(r => [obj.has(r[0]) ? obj.get(r[0]) + r[4] : r[4]]);
  range.offset(0, 4, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- In this modification, the values from both sheets are retrieved by one call. And, the new values for column "E" is created, and the new values are put into column "E". By this process, I thought that the process cost might be able to be reduced.
- When this script is run, I think that the same result with your showing script might be able to be obtained.

#### Note:

- This modified script is for your provided Spreadsheet. When you change it, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Before your edit it took 30 seconds for the script to fully run,, you have cut that down to 5 seconds! Thank you so much. I just have a quick question, what was the point of you using .reduce? I've never seen it used the way you did.

Comment: @projadm Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I just have a quick question, what was the point of you using .reduce?`, in this case, I used it by adding each value to a Map object using a condition `if (j.toString())` in order. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.